# search for millions of phrases in a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of 5 millions phrase (each phrase may be 2-10 words).
My input is a text (100 to 5000 words).
I want to find phrases (from 5 millions list) in the text.
Does Elasticsearch will fit for that scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate are you interested on phrases which contain some of the words which appear in the input text (regardless of order), or must words appear in (approximately) same order as well? It has major implications on which query type is the best fit.

Comment: Please see my comment on @E-Dahari response. Thanks

Comment: I have answered similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075518/elasticsearch-how-to-only-return-results-for-text-search-query-if-the-query-con/35077004#35077004), basically you index 5 million phrases(array of phrases) and give input text and ES will give you all the phrases back(using shingles, more details in the link)

Comment: My main concern is about the input - 5000 words. Is that a common scenario? Does ES will have performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Yes!
But, it depends:
Elasticsearch supports scaling horizontally which means that it can index even more data than what you have as long as it contains enough storage, memory and nodes (physical machines) in its cluster.

If you are referring to the search requests performance, with the data volume you are describing it should perform well. Again, as long as you have enough nodes in your cluster to distribute the indexed data and searches.

[here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scale.html)
 you can find more info about the subject.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think the question is hardly about scaling but more about how to express such queries and what is the expected performance from a single node cluster.

Comment: Thanks guys for responding. The question is about performance and usability. If I understand correctly, when the search/query input is 2 words, the engine will execute 2 queries, each for a single word, and will merge the results into a single response. Since my input may include 1000 and even 5000 words, I wondered if it is a valid scenario for Elasticsearch and the expected performance for that scenario.
Thanks.