# Elasticsearch: How to only return results for text search query if the query contains all of the words in at least one item in the indexed array?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have simple documents with a field called "keywords", which is indexed for text search. The keywords are an array of words and short phrases, like this:

{"keywords": ["restaurant manager", "chef", "bus boy"]}

The query must contain all of the words in at least one item in a doc's keywords for that doc to be returned.

Examples:

- "manager" should not return this doc.
- "bus" and "manager" should not return this doc.
- "restaurant manager" should return this doc.
- "chef" should return this doc.
- "restaurant manager chef" should return this doc and have a higher score.
- "restaurant manager unrelated words" should return this doc.
- "restaurant manager bus" should return this doc but, ideally, should not have a higher score than "restaurant manager".

The scoring is important, so I need to make it a query and not a filter.

I'm using Elasticsearch 1.7.

Comment: Please share the mapping so as to know whether the fields which are being indexed are analysed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with following setup.

```
POST your_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        },
        "shingle_analyzer":{
          "type" : "custom",
          "filter" :["lowercase","shingle_filter"],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "shingle_filter": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "keywords": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "shingle_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here I am using two different `analyzers`, one for `indexing` and one for `searching` because of the requirements. `keyword_analyzer` is needed to index the term as it is so that query for *manager* does not return document with *restaurant manager*. More on [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html). Now search needs [shingle filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) to generate `phrases` from the input text. Text like *This restaurant manager is kind* will be split into *This restaurant*, *restaurant manager*, *manager is* etc and you will get the desired results. You can use the [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-analyze.html) to see how analyzer works.

You index the document like this

```
PUT your_index/your_type/1
{
  "keywords": ["restaurant manager", "chef", "bus boy"]
}
```

and this type of query will give you documents back

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "keywords": "This restaurant manager is also a good chef"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you! :D

Comment: glad I could help you. It was a nice problem though.

Comment: Just so I understand: The keyword analyzer basically runs no analysis; a big part of this solution is not tokenizing on whitespace, right? I added a stemming filter, too, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. keywork analyzer does not do any analysis, that is why I have used `keyword tokenizer` so that we can apply filters like `lowercase`. This will solve case sensitive issue so *Chef*, *CHEF*,*chef* will all give you same results. Pure keyword analyzer wont allow us to use filters.

Comment: This is giving me strange results with scoring, unfortunately. If my keywords are `["investment banking", "accountant", "investment banker", "trader", "banker", "business analyst", "trading"]`, the following queries give these scores:

"banker": 1.23,

"banker accountant": 1.33,

"banker otherword": 0.31

"banker business analyst": 0.59

"business analyst": 0.31

I believe the issue is that the shingle filter outputs unigrams, but this is necessary for it to not ignore the single words.

The filtering is right but the scoring is messed up.

Comment: Here's the explanation of the result for a search against a doc with keywords `[
                  "software development",
                  "software developer",
                  "software engineer",
                  "software programmer",
                  "programmer"
               ]` for "software engineer"



https://gist.github.com/firerml/b801b0b6d17a23c2ac47

Comment: don't know if you're notified when I comment

Comment: I ll look into it after some time. I am at work now. It looks tricky though, tweaking score.